# Use Docker env vars with PHP 5.2.x

Tags: php, docker, environment-variables, fpm

I have inherited some code that was written with PHP **5.2**, and rather than installing myself, I have it running in a Docker container.

This system also depends on MySQL, so using Docker Compose and extracting the database credentials to a more secured location...

```
version: "3"

services:

    mariadb:
        image: mariadb:10.5
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
            MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USER}
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
            MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
        volumes:
            - ./conf/mariadb/initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/:ro
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"

    nginx:
        image: nginx:alpine
        depends_on: 
            - php-fpm
        volumes:
            - ${LOCAL_WORKING_DIR}:${REMOTE_WORKING_DIR}
            - ./conf/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
            - ./conf/nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
            # - ./conf/nginx/ssl/:/etc/nginx/ssl/
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
            # - "8443:443"

    php-fpm:
        build: 
            context: docker/app
            args:
                APP_ENV: ${APP_ENV}
                PHP_VERSION: ${PHP_VERSION}
                REMOTE_WORKING_DIR: ${REMOTE_WORKING_DIR}
        depends_on: 
            - mariadb
        working_dir: ${REMOTE_WORKING_DIR}
        volumes:
            - ${LOCAL_WORKING_DIR}:${REMOTE_WORKING_DIR}
            - ./conf/php/www.conf:/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf:ro
            # - ./conf/php/xdebug.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini:ro
            - ./conf/php/php-ini-overrides.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/99-overrides.ini:ro
        environment: 
            DB_HOST: mariadb:3306
            DB_USER: ${DB_USER}
            DB_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD} 
            DB_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
        ports:
            - "9000:9000"
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM devilbox/php-fpm:5.2-base
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

Using `phpinfo()` shows none of those values in `$_ENV` or `$_SERVER`, and `getenv()` returns empty strings.

---

I have seen latest `php-fpm` related issues saying this is solved with `clear_env: no`, [but this is only available in PHP-FPM 5.4+](https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php)

I have tried to use `composer` to install `dotenv`, but that seemed to require PHP7. Same for trying to install Vault to read database credentials remotely.

---

What else could I try to get this code to run as-is with minimal changes?

Options I have thought:

1. Start up a secondary REST server that exposes a preconfigured environment, then request to that from PHP... Seems hacky, but better than hard-coding database creds in any code, and would achieve a similar result as using Vault.
2. Mount my `.env` file, then parse it out, but that requires more code changes that would be removed later anyway

Comment: Put all the sensitive info in a file. Use gpg to encrypt the file with a password. The file is now safe to be kept aside the rest of the code. Before launching `php-fpm`, decrypt the file that contains the sensitive data with gpg, using a password that's provided as an ENV, so that the php can read from it. Although I believe your hacky idea is less hacky than mine :)). And yes, you also need to add gpg to that php-fpm image.

Comment: Docker env stuff always seems devilishly tricky to get right in my experience. But one thing I notice - you are not using [the `environment` syntax described in the docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#set-environment-variables-in-containers).  Try `- MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}`?

Comment: @Don'tPanic Tried both. They operate the same way. If I exec into the container, run `env | grep DB`, I see the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an XML file at `/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.conf` that contained the Environment variables, and filled it in using [`dockerize`](https://github.com/jwilder/dockerize)

```xml
<value name="environment">
    <!-- Add docker environment variables -->
    {{ range $k,$v := .Env }}{{ $parts := split $k "APP_" }}{{ if eq (len $parts) 2 -}}
    <value name="{{ index $parts 1 }}">{{ $v }}</value>
    {{ end }}{{- end -}}
    <!-- End Docker Env -->
```

With docker-compose having

```yaml
environment:
    APP_DB_HOST: mariadb:3306
    APP_DB_USER: ${DB_USER}
    APP_DB_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD} 
    APP_DB_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

most probably those env are overridden somewhere in image you are using.
docker compose allows to define a command to run on startup. So you can override env vars on startup to whatever you need:

```
command: bash -c "DB_HOST='mariadb:3306' && DB_USER='some_user ... & ./start_something.sh"
```

EDIT:

as comment mentioned php require all env to be in `php-fpm.conf`. strange as for me but it's easy enough to work around by adding env vars you need into this file in same `command:` statement of docker compose. Simple `echo "ENV_NAME" >> ..../php-fpm.conf` should help you.

or you can modify Dockerfile so your image has simple sh script which would dump all env vars into that php config.

i am modifying mongo config so works as replica set - works like a charm.

Comment: "Most probably"? Doubt it, considering [it's actually a feature](https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/74). And I can name the values anything, they turn up empty, so "overriden" seems wrong when its either "cleared" or "not gotten"

Comment: your link says its "php problem". anyway, you'v asked for an easy solution, here  it is. just modify `php-fpm.conf` in command like `echo "" >> ...`

Comment: That file is XML, so not seeing how that would help. The bash script in the github comments there also didn't work, even though I see the file does get loaded along with my other `php-fpm.conf.d` files